# passing parent component to children components using 'this' for access to parent's methods

Tags: angular, typescript

The way I learned to pass data back and forth from two components (one nested in the other) is to use `Input()` and `Output()` with event emitters.

I've also done it using a service class with Observables.

For my current project, I've been playing around with passing the instance of the parent directly into the child as follows:

HTML:

```
<my-child-component
   [parentComponent]="this">
</my-child-component>
```

TS:

```
@Input() parentComponent: ParentComponent;
```

this gives me direct access to the parent's methods from the children but I'm wondering if there are any gotchas or reasons I shouldn't be doing this.  As best I can tell, w/o running any performance tests or anything, this is working quite well.  I don't think this is really the 'angular way' to do things, but it sure makes things easier but I fully understand - easier is not always better.

I've tried researching this technique to see if I could find any reasons to NOT do it and have come up empty so figured I'd ask here....

Comment: Well from my perspective, `Input` is made to pass an object and has an impact on the changeDetection cycles. How will you handle onPush strategy if you put the whole parent component as an Input ? And could you not eventually have some circular dependency injection problems ? I trhow what I have in mind, just ideas.

Comment: All you're doing is passing a reference to the parent component so there's nothing really wrong with it. The only thing is you've coupled the child component to the parent, so the child is not reusable anywhere else. So when you do this you're committing to a single component type always being the parent, which may bite you later on. For example if the child is a form, I might want that same form inside a different component type later on, and I might want that parent to act differently when events occur in the form.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton ok thanks for the response.  I have actually already run into the exact issue you've described but fortunately my parent components are nearly identical.  In my OP I mentioned needing access to the parent's methods but in reality, I'm more interested in their properties which I use to show/hide certain elements on the HTML side depending on certain values from the parent.  Thanks for the input.